# Casorati–Weierstrass theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

Let $z=a$ be an isolated singularity of a complex-value function $f$.

I need to prove that:

*If exists $\delta>0$ such that $f(D(a,\delta)-\{a\})$ es not dense in $\mathbb{C}$, then $z=a$ is not an essencial singularity of $f$.*

Suppose $\delta>0$ such that $f(D(a,\delta)-\{a\})$ is not dense in $\mathbb{C}$. By definition, there exists $w_0\in\mathbb{C}$ and $\varepsilon>0$ that verify:
$$|f(z)-w_0|\geq \varepsilon \text{ for all } z\in \mathbb{C}, |z-a|<\delta$$

As $f(z)-w_0\ne 0$ in $D(a,\mu)-\{a\}$ for some $\mu>0$, we have that $\frac{f(z)-w_0}{z-a}$ has a pole in $z=a$ with orden $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Therefore: 
$$\frac{f(z)-w_0}{z-a}=\frac{g(z)}{(z-a)^m}\Rightarrow f(z)=\frac{g(z)}{(z-a)^{m-1}}+w_0$$
for some $g\in \mathcal{H}(D(a,\mu)-\{a\})$. We conclude that:
$$\lim_{z\to a}f(z)=\infty$$
and $z=a$ is not an essencial singularity of $f$.

**Is this reasoning correct?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a couple of nitpicks.

It is not clear why $f(z) - w_0 \neq 0$ implies the existence of a pole of $\frac{f(z)-w_0}{z-a}$ although this can be established by noticing that, on some small punctured disc around $a$,

$$ \left|{\frac{f(z)-w_0}{z-a}}\right| \ge \frac{\epsilon}{|z-a|} \implies \lim_{z \to a} \left|{\frac{f(z)-w_0}{z-a}}\right| = \infty $$

And you also need to get rid of the case $m = 1$ which kind of screws up your limit. But this can be dealt with since if $m = 1$ then the singularity at $a$ is removable because the limit of $f$ as $z \to a$ exists.